# WPF - Clickable content behind a scrollviewer

Tags: wpf, input, mouse, scrollviewer

Is it possible to have content behind a scrollviewer that still reacts to user mouse input?

```
<Grid>
    <Button Width="50" Height="50"/>
    <ScrollViewer Background="{x:Null}"/>
</Grid>
```

I've tried combinations of zindexes and null backgrounds, but can't seem to stop the scrollviewer from not tunneling the events down.

Comment: This sounds like a bit of a hack...what is your overall goal? There *may* be a better way to achieve it.

Comment: Setting IsHitTestVisible=False on scrollviewer will let you click the controls behind it. But this is weird requirement as doing this will make your scrollviewer completly transparent to any click on itself

Comment: did you solved this problem ?

Answer (score 3):

To prevent eating clicks, make your scroll viewer non-focusable:

```
<ScrollViewer Focusable="False" />
```

Comment: This works for me. I have some control that can be selected and have the scroll viewer inside. By using `Focusable="False"` I can select the control behind the scroll viewer and still interact with the scroll viewer normally (mouse wheel and drag of scroll bar both work without problems).

Answer (score 0):

The scrollviewer is eating click messages. You don't want to put things behind it.

It would be better to put things inside the scrollviewer. You can make a grid that contains the content and a usercontrol behind the content. The control can be themed to be transparent using a rectangle painted with the color "Transparent". The control would still be clickable, and would still fill up all the space within the scrolled content.

Comment: but then the thing that was meant to be behind would scroll

Comment: I assumed you just wanted clickability, and a solid scrolling invisible block won't matter. But if you wanted clickable areas you might have to handle the click on a scrollviewer and forward it to the content behind the scrollviewer.